# Is there a place in the universe where time doesn't exist?

Tags: time, universe, singularities

I've been reading that, all laws of nature and the universe stop existing at a singularity. So where there is a singularity, there cannot be time. A singularity is created when a property of a system becomes infinite. Singularities can be found at black holes, where the density is infinite. Time cannot exist there. Also, if you travel at the speed of light, you yourself will not feel time (means time will not exist for you). Thus, your one second will be equal to infinite seconds in the universe.

Don't know if it's valid though. What could be a strong proof for the same?

Comment: A singularity is a solution of an equation that indicates that the equation is invalid at that point and that it needs to be replaced with a better equation. It's a mathematical artifact, not a physical phenomenon. Time doesn't exist in thermodynamic equilibrium, which is kind of the opposite of a singularity. Why? Because time is what a clock shows and a clock is a system in strong disequilibrium.

Comment: @CuriousOne:  That is a very poor description of a singularity in general relativity.

Comment: @MBN: That is the only valid description of a singularity in general relativity. It's the point where we know that GR is guaranteed to be wrong.

Comment: @CuriousOne: That's simply not true! Singular space-times are (geodesically) incomplete space-times. A singularity is most certainly not as you say a solution of an equation that indicates that the equation is invalid. Can you give an example of such a solution in GR?

Comment: @MNB: Every solution on physics that gives an infinite result is simply false. OTOH, that's where one can learn the most about physics... when things fail, so that's a good reason to learn as much as we can about singularities. Not sure why you have elected GR to a religion, though. It's just a theory. Theories fail... that is what theories do, even GR.

Comment: @CuriousOne: I have no problem with GR failing, but that is not the issue here. It simply your way of phrasing what a singularity is, which is misleading and incorrect. Can you give an example as I asked above?

Comment: @MBN: When a theory predicts an infinity, it's done. There is no measurement that can measure infinities. If you can't measure it, it's not science. I didn't make the definition, but I actually take it seriously.

Comment: @CuriousOne: But I don't disagree with that. Just with your phrasing of what a singularity is. You said "a solution of an equation that indicates that the equation is invalid" can give an example?

Comment: @MBN: You mean like self-energy of a classical point charge, that kind of thing?

Comment: @CuriousOne: No, I mean a singularity in GR. That's what we are talking about. That's what I am complaining about. Singularities in GR are not what you wrote in your first comment.

Comment: @MBN: So you really think a principally unobservable infinity of an untested theory is a scientific fact? Hmmm... OK. Can't argue with that religion.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Where did you see me say anything like that!? All I'm arguing against is your description of what a singularity is. I've never claimed or expressed any opinion about whether I think if there are singularities in nature or not, or whether GR is complete or not. You continue to avoid to give an example! Instead you simply fight straw-men.

Comment: @MBN: You are arguing about a mathematical prediction of an untested theory that does not meet the definition of science. The only question is why you can't see that? The empirical definition of science is not that complicated.

Comment: @CuriousOne: No, I am not arguing anything like that. I am only objecting to your way of describing what a singularity in GR is. I don't understand why you keep changing the subject!!!

Comment: @MBN: Acknowledged. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a place in the universe where time doesn't exist?

and question:

> Don't know if it's valid though. What could be a strong proof for the same?

Please note that "proof" applies to mathematical formulae, not to physics. Physics confirms or falsifies a statement predicted by a mathematical formula. To confirm , one has to measure and measurement includes change and when there are changes time can be defined.

The comment by CuriousOne is correct. Singularities exist only in the mathematics and are a signal for the failure of the model at the singularity.

For example take electron positron attraction in classical electrodynamics. There is a singularity at r=0 . This is eliminated by the quantum mechanical solutions, which allow for [stable quantized states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positronium) . And if the electron and positron  fall on each other no infinity appears, but a decay into two photons.

> It has a mean lifetime of 125 picoseconds and decays preferentially into two gamma rays with energy of 511 keV each (in the center-of-mass frame). Detection of these photons allows to reconstruct the vertex of the decay and is used in the positron-emission tomography.

This clearly shows the limits of classical modeling with the infinities and the new physics modeling with quantum mechanics.

In a similar way, all measurements confirm special relativity, and its mathematical formulation  says that no massive particle can move with the speed of light because there is not enough energy in the universe to reach that velocity.

Comment: Your first paragraph reminds me of the immortal words of Donald Knuth "Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only proved it correct, not tried it."